# ISAPI Issues with CFWheels

Tags: iis, coldfusion, isapi, cfwheels, isapi-redirect

I am working with a brand new instance of `IIS on Windows Server 2012` and I am having trouble getting my CFWheels app to work. The issue it seems to be with `ISAPI filters and isapi_redirect.dll` because it's trying to find the file in the wrong folder. I tried adding a filter myself which I named jakarta and pointed it to the correct folder of the `dll` but now I am not getting anything but a blank screen and no error of any sort (before I was getting an error 500)

Anyone with a recommendation of what I need to do!?

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the site under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ instead of having it on my second HDD and the issue went away.... I would love to know why though so if anyone ever comes across this question please feel free to post

Comment: It went away because when you installed ColdFusion, 'Default Web Site' has a virtual directory called Jakarta that maps to a folder that has isapi_redirect.dll inside of it.

Comment: @coderpros that's what I did. I recreated the jakarta directory